# Deploy Rails 3.x app to Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using Heroku as a staging / testing server. For production, I plan to deploy to EC2, initially on 1 instance but the deployment should scale to multiple instances when needed. A quick search shows that there are web tools like Rubber and Chef which are designed for multi-EC2 instances deployment. But they do not look easy to grasp - atleast on first look.

I also see a simple guide here: 
http://boredwookie.net/index.php/blog/ruby-on-rails-3-passenger-mysql-on-amazon-ec2/
which looks more easy to follow. But I'm not sure how easy or hard it would be to scale up to multiple servers if needed later if I follow these steps.

Any guidance in this direction is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd say this is probably premature optimization. Heroku scales up pretty decently, and if you need more I'm *sure* they'd be glad to work with you to help. Most importantly, you won't know what needs to scale, how, or when until you've been in production a while and know what the slow points are, where the load problems are, etc. You'll have a *lot* more system administration work to do if you try to do it via EC2, and if you've never used Puppet or Chef a production EC2 deployment is probably not a good way to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Ruby Bitnami stack.

http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack

There is a AMI, installs very quick in EC2. Without to much fuzz. When it comes to scaling i don't know, but i guess its a good starting point.